# How to relate data (id's) to links for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to write a fairly complex dynamic web page, using JQuery AJAX, and I am struggling with how to relate my links (`<a ...>`) with the the data their tied to, such as action names, and data element ids.  I have pondered several different schemes, but I'm not sure I like any of them.

Building it into `onclick`, which means I have to configure it in the link generation.

```
<a onlick="func('abc', 123)">...</a>
```

Inserting it into the id of the link, which means parsing it out in JavaScript.

```
<a id="link_abc_123">...</a>
```

Putting the link in a div with hidden input elements...

```
<div>
   <a>...</a>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="abc"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123"/>
</div>
```

Is there a best practice or a commonly accepted way of structuring this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With HTML5, you have the luxury of using [`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) - for example:

```
<a href="somewhere" data-action="do-this" data-foo="bar">...</a>
```

Which jQuery actually has support for - calls to `$('a').data()` will include the `data-*` values in it.

Comment: I like this, there *is* something useful in HTML5 after all! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

*Best practice* should always be, to strictly separate Code.

That means, you shouldn't include any Javascript into your backend-source code. So personally I'm a big fan of either putting the necesarry data into the elements (your last example) when using a template-engine, or sending just the necesarry data on a separate request (*JSON* for instance) to the client.

Using jQuery, it's a very convinient way to create `data-` attributes, where you can store *any* information, while jQuery will translate the values from those attributes into the *data expandos*. For instance:

```
<div id="test" data-foo='bar' data-test='{"cool": "stuff"}'>Just a div</div>
```

When selecting that element with jQuery `var $test = $('#test')`, you can access:

```
$test.data('foo') // === 'bar'
$test.data('test').cool // === 'stuff'
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: As to sending the necessary data on a separate request, how would I relate the vanilla link to the data I would get back?

Comment: @C.Ross: well, you would need to structure the data in way you can assign it properly. For instance, give the related nodes an ID and use that id as keys for your data object and as value, whatever it should be.

Comment: Nice answer :-) I would do it the exact same way

Answer (score 1):

For simple things, I use a function like:

```
function getIdStr(i, sDelim) {
    if (typeof i != "string") {
        var i = $(i).attr("id");
    }
    var arr = i.split(sDelim || /_|-/);
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        return arr[arr.length-1];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

// usage
$(function(){
    $(".data .action").click(function(){
        doSomething(getIdStr(this)); // -> 123
    });
});
```

For something heavier, you might try to attach a `data` to the topmost container.

Answer (score 1):

i would go with the new [Custom Data Attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) HTML5 brings along.

Just use this `<a data-action="foo" data-id="bar">...</a>`

Also, jQuery [already has support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to get these data-attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom property to the input and access it in javascript.
eg

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="abc" yourproperty='<%= Eval("YourDataID") %>'/>
```